# Are some polyketides enzymes?

Tags: metabolism, enzymes

I am currently reading a "book" (rather an article) called "Protein Modelling & Molecular Docking: Modeller, Autodock".

The abstract starts with the following sentence :

> Polyketides are a large family of complex enzymes synthesized by
>   polyketide synthases.

Before reading this article, I knew nothing about polyketides. I looked it up online, and I saw that they were secondary metabolites, which adds up with the rest of the article. However, I could not find any mention of some polyketides being enzymes, hence my question:

Are some polyketides enzymes or is this a simple mistake in the article ?

Comment: It's a typo. Now let's close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  Polyketide synthases (PKS) are the enzymes that synthesize polyketides.  PKS are derived from fatty acid synthases via evolution.  Polyketides are of great interest becaus many are of important medical use.